# Is it possible to use Chrome Web Store Payments in chrome packaged apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

recently I have discovered that I'm unable to get OAuth token for packaged app. Thus raised a question: Is it possible to use Chrome Web Store Payments?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Animation Editor",
  "version": "0.139.3",

  "description": "animation editor",
  "icons": {"128": "logo.png" },
  "app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["start.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/"
  ],
    "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "361228830972.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },
  "short_name": "aEditor"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find that you can't use OAuth with packaged apps? The documentation does acknowledge that with packaged apps, it is relatively easy to manipulate the source because the user downloads it, but you can still use the APIs.

### Documentation

- [Packaged App info](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)
- [Payments and licensing FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-payments-01)
- [Chrome identity API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html)
- [Check for payment with the Licensing API](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/check_for_payment)

Essentially, after setting you app ID up in the [Chrome APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1)  you use the `getAuthToken` call in the Chrome Identity API which authenticates the user account. Then, you can pass that token information to the Licensing API for payment collection (through the Chrome Web Store) or verification.

Comment: in the last document you posted is written then I should be able to get OAuth token in dashboard. But i'm not able - there is no link OAuth setup!!! Thus I assumed that this documentation  applies to not-packaged apps. Do you know the other way of getting OAuth token? Or I really don't need it?

Comment: What region are you setting up the app in? You need to be in one of Google's [supported regions](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/pricing#seller) in order to use the Web Store for payment. Another option for getting a token is to use the `launchWebAuthFlow` from the Identity API, but you'll need your own way to authenticate users.

Comment: I'm in Netherlands which is supported region. In the edit page of my app in dashboard I've chosen "all regions" but choosing only USA doesn't help me to get OAuth token.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already registered your app with the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)? If you haven't done that yet, you need to register before the app will show up in your dashboard.

Comment: All I did is logged in in Google API Console from developer account and turned on "Chrome Web Store API" switch. How to register my app there?

Comment: I did registered now BUT in section **Copy key to your manifest** of the documentation(#3 in your list) sais: Copy the "key" in the installed manifest.json and paste it into your app's source manifest file. Didn't do that because chrome reject to upload manifest with key field. How to proceed with this key?
btw thank you very much for helping!!!

Comment: Would you post your updated `manifest.json` file? It would help me figure out what the problem is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46529/discussion-between-brian-bennett-and-qvatra)

Comment: I've got the chrome.identity.getAuthToken() work in my app (I followed documentation again step by step) but i'm still unable to upload manifest with a "key" field.. I've notice though that my app id doesnt change after reinstall or after update. Does it mean that I don't really need to provide the "key" fild in the manifest?